# Error looping through table and removing rows

Tags: sql, while-loop

I am trying to create an SQL script to loop through a table and check whether the AppID field apperas in another table. Then if it finds the record in another table it deletes the row and sets a variable if it deletes or not.

So far i have created the loop and it sets the variable if it finds the record however i have tried to add the delete statement and it is producing an error saying 'Incorrect syntax near 'ELSE'' error message

```
Use APTLive
Go

declare @RowNum int, @CustId nchar(5), @Name1 nchar(25)
declare @ProdCount int
declare @PROD nchar(5)
select @CustId=MAX(ID) FROM TempAppTable     --start with the highest ID
Select @RowNum = Count(*) From TempAppTable      --get total number of records
WHILE @RowNum > 0                          --loop until no more records
BEGIN   
select @Name1 = AppID from TempAppTable where ID = @CustID    --get other info from that row
select @ProdCount = Count(*) from ProductType where AppRefID = @Name1    --GET APP COUNT ProductType

print cast(@RowNum as char(12)) + ' ' + @Name1 + ' ' + cast(@ProdCount as char(3)) 

If @ProdCount    > 0    SET @PROD = 'Y'  DELETE FROM ProductType    WHERE AppRefID = @Name1     ELSE SET @PROD = 'N'


select top 1 @CustId=ID from TempAppTable where ID < @CustID order by ID desc
    set @RowNum = @RowNum - 1
END
```

Can anyone let me know why i am getting this error? Is it because an IF can only perform one task when it returns true or false?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: You need to use BEGIN and END for your `If @ProdCount  > 0` since you're using multiple statements

Comment: sorry i missed off the starting use DBMS line

Comment: Do you mean BEGIN IF ELSE END?

Comment: Check the answer and see if it work @JessicaNutt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed `BEGIN` & `END` for your `IF` condition, since your IF contains more than ONE instruction you need to have BEGIN & END in code block

```
Use APTLive
Go

declare @RowNum int, @CustId nchar(5), @Name1 nchar(25)
declare @ProdCount int
declare @PROD nchar(5)
select @CustId=MAX(ID) FROM TempAppTable     --start with the highest ID
Select @RowNum = Count(*) From TempAppTable      --get total number of records
WHILE @RowNum > 0                          --loop until no more records
BEGIN   
select @Name1 = AppID from TempAppTable where ID = @CustID    --get other info from that row
select @ProdCount = Count(*) from ProductType where AppRefID = @Name1    --GET APP COUNT ProductType

print cast(@RowNum as char(12)) + ' ' + @Name1 + ' ' + cast(@ProdCount as char(3)) 

If @ProdCount    > 0    
BEGIN   -- [Added Mjoy]
   SET @PROD = 'Y'   
   DELETE FROM ProductType    WHERE AppRefID = @Name1     
END     -- [Added Mjoy]
ELSE SET @PROD = 'N'


select top 1 @CustId=ID from TempAppTable where ID < @CustID order by ID desc
    set @RowNum = @RowNum - 1
END
```